# Is it okay to perform async operations without anybody "knowing" about it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous

I'm using a COM library with [RCWs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx).  I've always found it's a best practice to manually release any unmanaged resources and garbage collect before they go out of scope.  I don't want this to "slow down" my application, and I don't care when this actually finishes, if at all, before the application exits.  So I have this method:

```
// best effort:
internal static void CleanupComObjects(params object[] toRelease)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var t = Task.WhenAll(toRelease.Select((x) => 
            Task.Run(() => 
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(x))));

        t.Wait();
        System.GC.Collect();
    });
}
```

Is it OK to do this without any clients or users of my API/application knowing or caring that async code is running, as long as it doesn't produce any side effects other than what is expected by the caller, or is there something I haven't though about which could result in unexpected problems? (*<-- To "primarily opinion based" close voters, note this last line.*)

Comment: Aren't you essentially just replicating what the garbage collector would do anyway here?

Comment: Trust me I've had hair-pulling-out issues with COM libraries in the past that were definitively and satisfactorily resolved by using this approach (without the async, that is, just the ReleaseComObject and GC stuff).  You never know what to expect when dealing with RCWs.

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised anyone is still using COM. Didn't this get dropped years ago.

Comment: Are you serious?  I'm mainly an [enterprise software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_software) developer, and one of the things I deal with a lot is automating email systems.  One tool that is invaluable for this -- which is, unfortunately, only available as a COM library -- is [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm).  The firm I work for also has a document management system (as do thousands of firms) called [Imanage](https://imanage.com/), whose DLLs are also only COM.  Thus, I've used RCWs a lot.

Comment: We send lots of automated emails. We mostly use email services such as [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/). But well, this isn't really helping with you issue. Hope you get a solution

Comment: It's not for sending emails.  That's easy.  It's for connecting to mailboxes, drilling down to folders, working with email, saving attachments or working with embedded emails, appointments, contacts, etc., moving items, creating folders, deleting folders, renaming folders, etc.  I don't know much about mailchimp, but it's never shown up on my radar for this kind of thing, so I doubt it does that.

Comment: Plus our mail repositories are on site.  Lawyers typically don't like storing stuff in the cloud and accessing it with third-party, external services.  They worry a lot.

Comment: @Liam: it used to be quite common for unmanaged handles to remain live for a long time if there was no particular memory pressure, the GC would just not bother collecting them since it felt there was enough memory (at least in older .NET versions running on client machines). I believe newer .NET versions with "server GC" algorithms do a slightly better job. But anyway, the fact that the `IDisposable` interface exists and is used all over BCL is a good indicator that cleaning up unmanaged resources manually, as soon as possible, is a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't care when this actually finishes, if at all, before the application exits

That statement seems in conflict with your other one:

> I've always found it's a best practice to manually release any unmanaged resources and garbage collect before they go out of scope

If you really didn't care, it seems to me you could just let .NET manage the COM objects' lifetimes, as the RCW is intended to accomplish.

That said, I don't see anything wrong with your approach per se. The implementation seems heavy-handed to me, but this sort of "fire-and-forget" approach occurs in many other scenarios. You could even argue that .NET's basic garbage collection algorithm is an example (after all, you don't typically know or have control over when or how it happens…it "just does").

Personally, I would write it in a more streamlined fashion:

```
internal static async Task CleanupComObjects(params object[] toRelease)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(toRelease.Select((x) => 
        Task.Run(() => 
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(x))));

    System.GC.Collect();
}
```

Or even:

```
internal static Task CleanupComObjects(params object[] toRelease)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (object o in toRelease)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
        }

        System.GC.Collect();
    });
}
```

(Returning `Task` from the method gives the caller the opportunity to observe the completion of the operation. It's not required to, but you may find going forward there's a good reason to, e.g. so that you can detect exceptions that might occur.)

In other words, it's not clear to me why you want the calls to `ReleaseComObject()` to occur concurrently. Depending on where these objects come from and the apartment model, you could just be asking for trouble trying to do it that way.

Speaking of which, the other detail missing from your question is what apartment model you're dealing with here. If these are STA objects, your operations are going to get marshalled by .NET back to the owning thread, meaning any attempt to release them concurrently with any other code running on that thread (whether that's other code unrelated to the objects or the other calls to `ReleaseComObject()`) will be pointless. You might initiate the release concurrency, but the release operations and your other code in that thread will all get serialized anyway.

All that said…

In general, it is my preference to write code that *solves a problem*. Is there a specific problem that has occurred here that you are trying to address? The code is already a bit irregular in that you aren't relying on the normal GC management of .NET to deal with your objects. Then you add to that irregularity by shifting your explicit management of them to other threads, something that may or may not even be successful depending on the type of COM objects you're dealing with.

I would hope that you're doing all that work for a good reason. But what is that reason? What specific problem is it that you're trying to solve? Have you been able to confirm that this type of code does in fact solve that problem?

It seems to me that those are important questions, but there's not enough information in the post above to address them. So I encourage you to investigate that on your own. You might want to consider a separate Stack Overflow question in which you provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem you're trying to solve, to solicit advice for alternative means to solving that problem.